# increment jQuery val() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  have a function myTimer() which makes a counter. I want to increment input value when user clicks next button and repeat counter. The problem is every time it puts a new value of (rem) in input but I want to increase it by new rem.
`dur` is a variable declared in myTimer() it's user entered to make count, and seconds the variable counted, it's declared in myTimer() too.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
       var rem= 0;            
        $("#next").click(function(){
            rem+= dur-seconds-1;
           $("input#time").val(rem);

             myTimer();
       });
});
```

Comment: what is dur and seconds in it ?

Comment: What is `dur-seconds` ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please click the [<>] button in the editor and create a full example. Then explain what is expected and actual result

Comment: What is  dur-seconds?

Comment: is dur undefined  ?

Comment: i editted the question

Answer (score -1):

You have declared JS variable `var rem= 0;`  inside 
document.ready.

Declare it globally, before `$(document).ready()`